# wxPython py2exe app not bundling properly?

Tags: python, dll, wxpython, py2exe

I've got a wxPython application that I'm trying to make into an exe using py2exe, but I'm having some trouble. I've got `MSVCP90.dll` in the same directory as the script, and after py2exe finished, it says "The program can't start because MSVCR90.dll is missing..." when launching the exe. Why isn't it finding it?

While it's py2exe'ing, I also get the following:

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files']
...
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.
...
  OLEAUT32.dll - C:\PATH
  USER32.dll - C:\PATH
...
  MSVCP90.dll - C:\PathToTheDllInMyScriptsFolder
```

Is there something I'm missing here? How hard can it be to take a .py wxPython app and turn it into a .exe wxPython app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to handle this is to exclude MSVCP90.dll from the py2exe package.  Here's a part of one of my setup scripts that does this:

```
dll_excludes = ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll',
                'tk84.dll','MSVCP90.dll']

setup(
    data_files = data_files,
    options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 2,
                          "optimize": 2,
                          "includes": includes,
                          "excludes": excludes,
                          "packages": packages,
                          "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                          "bundle_files": 1,
                          "dist_dir": "dist",
                          "xref": False,
                          "skip_archive": False,
                          "ascii": False,
                          "custom_boot_script": '',
                         }
              },
    zipfile = None,
    windows = [filename]
    )
```

You will then be responsible for assuring that the MS Visual C++ runtime is installed on end user's machine.  You can get it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

My experience is that is rare to find a Windows machine that lacks the visual c runtime, but you'll need to be ready to handle this just in case.

good luck,
Mike

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues with py2exe. My project uses additional libraries like wxPython and Requests.

This worked for me:

1. Create project using gui2exe
2. Specify very basic settings like Target Classes and Data Files (in my case - images, sqlite database etc.) and compile project.
3. In `dist` directory You will find compiled project that should work on our machine.
4. Next steps are mixture of this two tutorials: [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step52) and [cx_freeze](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html)
5. In `dist` create directory `Microsoft.VC90.CRT`
6. Copy to this directory files `msvcm90.dll`, `msvcp90.dll`, `msvcr90.dll` from `C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_x-ww_d08d0375`
7. Copy also `C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_x-ww_d08d0375.manifest`, but rename to `Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest`

   I have done this using Win XP 32-bit and Python 2.7.3 and succesfully launched compiled application on another xp machine and windows 7.

Comment: *sigh*. Why can't this be like py2app? You type `py2app myscript.py myicon.icns`, and you've got a working program.

Answer (score 2):

do you have any desire to try [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).
I too had tried py2exe for wxPython project and received many obscure bugs.
Pyinstaller came to light on the first try, and I thought it was even easier.

Comment: I tried that, too, but it didn't seem to work any better. I'll try it again in a bit.

Comment: Here is content of my bat file to create exe 


`echo python Configure.py

echo python Makespec.py --onefile D:\project.py

c:\Python27\python.exe Build.py project\project.spec`

Comment: Can you do it with a command prompt command? And is the Build.py a py2exe script file?

Comment: Do you mean: do 'compiled' .exe work with command prompt like the source .py file? - Yes.
Build.py is pyinstaller scipt

Comment: No, I mean instead of making a batch file, can you just `C:\Python27\python.exe Build.py`, and have Build.py be a *py2exe* file

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand why you say py2exe. I am talking about pyinstaller.
To create a new build I just run `python Build.py project\project.spec`

Comment: Okay. Does PyInstaller require the MSVC.dll files?

Comment: :-)
I've never seen any *.dll required for PyInstaller. I hope all requirements already included in a package.

Answer (score 2):

After nearly a year of trying to build one with no success. Finally got it. You must exclude both files 'msvcp90.dll', 'msvcr71.dll'.

dll_excludes = ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll',
                'tk84.dll', 'msvcp90.dll', 'msvcr71.dll']